# Accessing iSeries database with Python3. File not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm running python 3 on an iseries and I want to connect to the local database. The command

```
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect('XXXX','YYYYY','ZZZZ')
```

is successful but when I run

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM V40DTALIB.SCHOOL"
```

I get the error

```
SCHOOL in V40DTALIB type *FILE not found. SQLSTATE=42704 SQLCODE=-204
```

The file is there and the credentials I'm using are authorised. I think it's because the library is on an IASP. Normally this would be mounted by the user profile job description but this is obviously not happening. If I replace the file with a QGPL one (in sysbase) I don't get this error.

I'd like to run SETASPGRP ASPGRPXXX.

I've tried

```
ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, "call qcmdexc('SETASPGRP ASPGRP(IASPEXAM)')")
```

```
Exception: Trigger program or external routine detected an error. SQLSTATE=38501 SQLCODE=-443
```

I don't know where to look for further information or job logs etcetera. Anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a closer look at this line...

```
conn = ibm_db.connect('XXXX','YYYYY','ZZZZ')
```

I believe `'XXXX'` is the database name.  If you have a IASP, you likely have at least two databases.  Make sure you have the right one for the IASP.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. Its gratifying to see data streaming out.

Comment: @jimwatterson remember to mark the answer as accepted.